# How to convert HashMap to JSON in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, hashmap

I have HashMap in Kotlin

```
val map = HashMap<String, String>()
map.put("key1","value1");
map.put("key2","value2");
map.put("key3","value3");
```

How to convert it into String in JSON format? like

```
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"}
```

Comment: use Gson to convert Hashmap to Json

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use `org.json` which is shipped with Android:

```
JSONObject(map).toString()
```

Comment: What about string to map ?

Comment: @ZulqurnainJutt, do you mean a string with a JSON object inside, i.e. backwards conversion?

Comment: It gives me an error `Java type mismatch expected (Mutable)Map<(raw) Any?, (raw) Any?>! but found (Mutable)Map<String!, String!>. Use explicit cast`

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS, reported: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-53407/HashMap-not-recognized-as-subtype-of-Javas-raw-Map

Comment: @Miha_x64 thanks I guess I ran out of option now

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS, look at the code snippet on YouTrack, it contains a workaround.

Comment: I had to wrap the individual values in the map with JsonPrimitive() to get this to work.

Answer (score 21):

You can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for that,

Here is the example,

```
val map = HashMap<String, String>()
map.put("key1","value1");
map.put("key2","value2");
map.put("key3","value3");

val gson = Gson()
Log.d("TAG", gson.toJson(map).toString())
```

and the oputput is,

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}
```

Answer (score 9):

Use [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#introduction-and-references):

```
import kotlinx.serialization.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.*

fun main() {
   var store = HashMap<String, String>()
   var jsonString= Json.encodeToString(store)
   var anotherStore = Json.decodeFromString(jsonString)
}
```

Comment: Got `SerializationException: Serializer for class 'Any' is not found.` with a hashmap of `<String, Any>`

Answer (score 2):

If someone has problems in Koltlin, you can use gson like this:

```
val gson = Gson()
val json = JSONObject(gson.toJson(map))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to convert a HashMap to JSON in Kotlin. Here are two methods:

1. Using JSONObject and JSONArray:

   - Create a HashMap with some key-value pairs:

     ```
     val hashMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
     hashMap["name"] = "John"
     hashMap["age"] = 30
     hashMap["married"] = true
     ```
   - Convert the HashMap to a JSONObject:

     ```
     val jsonObject = JSONObject(hashMap)
     ```
   - Convert the JSONObject to a JSON string:

     ```
     val jsonString = jsonObject.toString()
     ```
2. Using the Gson library:

   - Add the Gson dependency to your project by adding the following line to your app-level build.gradle file:

     ```
     implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
     ```
   - Create a HashMap with some key-value pairs:

     ```
     val hashMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
     hashMap["name"] = "John"
     hashMap["age"] = 30
     hashMap["married"] = true
     ```
   - Convert the HashMap to a JSON string using Gson:

     ```
     val gson = Gson()
     val jsonString = gson.toJson(hashMap)
     ```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [klaxon](https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon), then it would simply be:

```
val json = Klaxon().toJsonString(map)
```